# Adding items to dictionary if condition is true, else dont - python

Tags: python, dictionary, conditional-statements

I'm trying to take an existing process:

```
if self.path_object is not None:
    dictpath = {}
    for path in self.path_object:
        self.params = path.pathval.split("?")[0]
        self.params = path.pathval.split("&", 2)
        if any(item in path.pathval for item in self.params):
            out = list(map(lambda v: v.split("=")[0] +"=" + str(self.fuzz_vectors), self.params))
            dictpath[path] = out
    print dictpath
```

**Update** For those finding this who looking for help with `split()` method . I've found it easier to do it with the [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#) library. Thanks to user DarinDouglass for pointing this out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are assigning the `path` to `dictpath` no matter what. The assignment will run EVERY iteration of the for loop.

To fix this you can either change `pass` to `continue` or move `dictpath[path] = out` into the true block of your if statement. The latter is the better option because you can then remove the `else` statement.

---

EDIT: Another problem is happening in your if statement. Let's break it down. What your conditional says is this:

- Is there any item in `self.params` that can be found in `path.pathval`.

The problem with this is that this will ALWAYS be `True` because `self.params` is a sub-set of `path.pathval`; that is, you **create** `self.params` from `path.pathval`.

Here is a example to show what I mean:

```
pathval = 'www.example.com/some_path/?param1=1&param2=2'

# params = ['www.example.com/some_path/?param1=1', 'param2=2']
params = pathval.split('&', 2)

# Essentially says: is the string 'www.example.com/some_path...' in pathval? YES
if any(item in pathval for item in params)
    # Add to dict
```

---

Once your code is fixed, feel free to post it to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as I have some statements that are more applicable there.

Comment: Please see updated code. This is *still* containing paths like www.somesite.com/path/path/path and somesite.com?id=6&param2=blah, when it should only contain urls with parameters

Comment: Is there something wrong with it? I'm sorry I dont see it. I would appreciate any pointers here

Comment: Thanks for that. I understand that self.params is dervied from path.pathval. How can I made it dependent on the self.params only? If I understand it correctly its saying if there is <any> object in path.pathval, then split and add to dict

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54657/discussion-between-darindouglass-and-codetalk).